# Error #1044 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' to database 'information_schema'

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, information-schema

Alright, so here is the scenario

I performed a full backup on my mysql server today. Now when I try to import that .sql dump file, I get the error mentioned in the title and it does not load all the other databases.

How can I get around this so phymyadmin will allow me to import the whole file, or is there a way I could "remove" information_schema from the sql dump

Thanks

Comment: To "remove" information_schema from the dump, open the file in notepad and delete those lines. It's just a text file of sequential queries to run.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As Dan Grossman said:

> To "remove" information_schema from the dump, open the file in notepad
>   and delete those lines. It's just a text file of sequential queries to
>   run.

Comment: what if the file is too big?

Answer (score 3):

Open information_schema and run

```
FLUSH TABLES
```

This should clear the information_schema CACHE and will stop the error as it "resyncs" the tables to the latest schema

Comment: This should be the selected answer actually! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I use a program called Notepad++.

You open your sql file and the program will put it in a way where you can clearly see what the information_schema database is trying to do and why it is failing every time. You can safely remove that part of the database.

Then I install a WAMP on my pc, run a mysql program (mysql front) and import the database.  After importing I have full access to the tables and databases.

Just export what you want and then just import then to your new database.

Answer (score -1):

CREATE a new database and then then try to connect using that new db then run the schema and then try to execute the databases.